# Can I use C++ TR1 in VS2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, tr1

We have some code written with TR1, e.g.:

```
#include <tr1/functional>
...
typedef std::tr1::function<void(int)> MyFunction;
..
```

It works fine by compiling with GCC, but failed with VS2010.

Our code has [compatibility issue with C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482596/undefined-reference-to-stdbasic-string) so I'm afraid I can't simply switch to C++11. I don't want to introduce boost into our code either.

Is there any pack or something I should download for VS2010 to make it support TR1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS 2010 supports TR1 out of the box. You don't need a `tr1/` at the beginning of the file name when you include it though.

```
#include <functional>

typedef std::tr1::function<void(int)> MyFunction;
```

Note that TR1 doesn't specify a file name for the headers, so as far as conforming with TR1 goes, either one is about the same as the other.

Answer (score 4):

You can directly use `<functional>` in VS 2010. So it'd be

```
#include <functional>
...
typedef std::function<void(int)> MyFunction;
..
```

VS 2010 moved what was previously in `std::tr1` into the usual `std` namespace, but VS 2008 still uses `std::tr1`. That said, you should still be able to use `tr1` namespace explicitly, if you need it I.e.

```
#include <functional>
...
typedef std::tr1::function<void(int)> MyFunction;
..
```

is valid too (note the header file included doesn't have `tr1/`).

**Relevant Links:**

[What are differences between std, tr1 and boost (as namespaces and/or libraries)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682919/what-are-differences-between-std-tr1-and-boost/4682954#4682954)

[Why does VS2010 maintain the std::tr1 namespace?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2fbf8f76-354f-43e6-a77f-09f9a334d838/just-a-curiosity-why-does-vs2010-maintain-the-stdtr1-namespace-i-presume-its-just-a-legacy)